# finding function with limit and derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The limit is:
$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{7^{3x}-7^9}{x-3}$
This is equal to the derivative of a function f at a point a (that is, f′(a)).

how do you figure out what the function f is and the value of a ? 
I figured out $f'(a)= -231557$ but i do not know how to use this for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{7^{3x}-7^9}{x-3}=7^9\lim_{h\to0}\frac{7^{3h}-1}h=7^9\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{3\ln 7h}-1}h=3\ln7\cdot 7^9$$

as $a^y=(e^{\ln a})^y=e^{y\ln a}$

and $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

Comment: Do you know or are you allowed to use L'Hospital rule ?

Answer (score 0):

$$(7^{3x})'\Big|_{x=3} = \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{7^{3x}-7^{3\cdot 3}}{x-3}.$$

Hence
$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{7^{3x}-7^{3\cdot 3}}{3-x} = -7^{3\cdot3} \cdot \ln 7\cdot 3$$

Comment: why minus in the result?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, because denominator is changed.